# Remove special character from column values using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has a column where I would like to remove all periods within those values.

Data

```
Date       ID
Q1.2021    A
Q1.2021    A
Q2.2022    B
Q2.2022    B
```

Desired

```
Date       ID
Q1 2021    A
Q1 2021    A
Q2 2022    B
Q2 2022    B
```

Doing

```
  def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
    return text
# Apply to the DF series
df['new_column'] = df['column'].apply(remove_punctuations)
```

I am thinking I can use a function, however, is there a simpler way?
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Try `df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace('\.',' ', regex=True)`

Comment: I believe must use the str accessor ```df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('\.',' ', regex=True)```